# How to add a github repo site (that isn't the main one) on namecheap?

Tags: git, github, subdomain

I know that to connect a github site to namecheap you do:

`HOST NAME   IP ADDRESS              RECORD TYPE     TTL
@           192.30.252.153          A (Address)     1800
www         <username>.github.io    CNAME (Alias)   1800`

On github, you can have more than one site by: http://username.github.io/REPONAME.

However, when I add another line on namecheap for http://username.github.io/REPONAME like the following:

```
www       <username>.github.io/REPONAME    CNAME (Alias)   1800
```

it doesn't work. So how do I add to namecheap.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be necessary. Once your username.github.io domain is set up with a CNAME to *yourdomain.com*, your repos' GitHub pages will be served at *yourdomain.com/repo*. Make sure you have GitHub pages enabled for your repo and that the CNAME for your username.github.io is working correctly.